php or javascript. Need to Get Link ID sorted as string from Domdocument to use for building custom assigned links
$version = '1.1';
$sortBy = isset($_GET['sortBy']) ? $_GET['sortBy'] : 'PUBLISHED_DESC';
$articleClassName = 'relative isolate sf-search-ad cursor-pointer overflow-hidden relative transition-all outline-none p-10 hover:bg-aqua-50 focus:bg-aqua-50 sf-search-ad-legendary  -m-8';
$merchantID = '3553552';
$finn_link = 'https://www.finn.no/car/used/search.html?orgId='.$merchantID.'&sort='.$sortBy;
$finnTagName = 'article';
$finnTagLink = 'a';
$finnAttrName = 'class';
$finnAttrValue = $articleClassName;

$finnDom = new DOMDocument;
$finnDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$finnDom->loadHTMLFile($finn_link);

$finnHtml = getTags( $finnDom, $finnTagName, $finnAttrName, $finnAttrValue );

function getTags( $finnDom, $finnTagName, $finnAttrName, $finnAttrValue ){
    $finnHtml = '';
    $domxpath = new DOMXPath($finnDom);
    $newDom = new DOMDocument;
    $newDom->formatOutput = true;
    $filtered = $domxpath->query("//$finnTagName" . '[@' . $finnAttrName . "='$finnAttrValue']");
    $i = 0;
    while( $myItem = $filtered->item($i++) ){
        $node = $newDom->importNode( $myItem, true );
        $newDom->appendChild($node);
    }
    $finnHtml = $newDom->saveHTML();
    return $finnHtml;
}
?>

I need that each article tag that has a link with ID in it would be saved in separate array either to database or anyother way so it could be accesesed to buid a custom link related to object (add).
this is how ny "article class looks like after sorting with DomDocument:
<article class="relative.....">
    <a href="https://www.finn.no/car/used/ad.html?finnkode=346236078" id="346236078">Link to add</a>
</article>

I need to be able to gather ID and change link in final anchor tag so I can use it to render Another DomDocument when my link is clicked this should not redirect to the other site but should stay on my site.
I was thinking about foreach loop but dont really know how to implement this in DOM.
Anyone has a hint or something how could I go about it. Maybe some type of compare like if search for
<a ... id="346236078"> 

and convert\make variables to
$idLink1='346236078' 

for each instance. But then I dont know if will be able to full right link id for each article...
I might just add code and save those variables to database or something so its easier...

The question is not entirely clear. I can't figure out if you want to edit the HTML document server-side (before sending it to the browser) or client-side (when the browser has already received it). It's also unclear whether you want to edit the original page or whether you want to create a new page containing only the modified tags.
This is a possible solution for server side, I adapted your code. The output is the original document with changes applied, if you only need the changed tags, you can remove comments where indicated.
I have provided the $conversionIds array which contains the data modifications to be applied.
$conversionIds = [
    
    '0001' => 'xyzk',
    '1234' => '0000',
    '346236078' => 'abcde',
];

.....
$finnDom->loadHTMLFile($finn_link, LIBXML_NOERROR);

// de-comment to create a new DOM document
/*$finnHtml =*/ parseDom ($finnDom, $finnTagName, $finnAttrName, $finnAttrValue, $conversionIds);

// replace with the commented version to create a new DOM document
$newHtml = $finnDom->saveHTML();  // $newHtml = $finnHtml->saveHTML();


function parseDom ($finnDom, $finnTagName, $finnAttrName, $finnAttrValue, &$conversionIds)
{
// de-comment to create a new DOM document
//    $newDom = new DOMDocument;
//    $newDom->formatOutput = true;

    $domXpath = new DOMXPath($finnDom);
    $q = "//$finnTagName" . '[@' . $finnAttrName . "='$finnAttrValue']";
    $filtered = $domXpath->query($q);

    foreach ($filtered ?: [] as $myItem) {

        foreach ($myItem->getElementsByTagName('a') as $childNode) {  // <~~~ get all <a> sub-elements

            $id = $childNode->getAttribute('id');

            if ($conversionIds[$id] ?? false) {

                $href = $childNode->getAttribute('href');

                $components = parse_url($href);
                $queryStrArr = [];
                parse_str($components['query'] ?? '', $queryStrArr);

                if (isset($queryStrArr['finnkode'])) {

                    $queryStrArr['finnkode'] = $conversionIds[$id];  // <~~~ replace finnkode in the query string of href
                    $queryStr = http_build_query($queryStrArr);

                    $newHref = ($components['scheme'] ?? 'https') .
                               ($components['host'] ?? 'default.host.name') .
                               ($components['path'] ?? 'default.path') .
                               '?' . $queryStr;

                    $childNode->setAttribute('href', $newHref);
                }

                $childNode->setAttribute('id', $conversionIds[$id]); // <~~~ replace id attribute

//          de-comment to create a new DOM document
//                $node = $newDom->importNode ($myItem, true);
//                $newDom->appendChild($node);
            }
        }
    }

    // de-comment to create a new DOM document
    // return $newDom;
}


https://bbvest.no/biler-til-salgs/ visit this. This page is generated by DomDocument geting all article tags from original page. If you try to click on any of adds you will be redirected to original site. My goal is to load each add with new domdocument that will render page of original add on my site. so thats why I need to find way to make it work.

Let me understand better: instead of changing the source page you want to collect the html fragments to create a new page where the href attributes point to your site, is this correct? Have you already prepared the new pages on your site? Can you provide an example URL for the new pages?
